# How to detect if an embedded swf is created with Flex or Flash in javascript

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, actionscript-3

Is there a way (in javascript) to detect if an embedded .swf was created with Flash Professional or Flex.

We have a page with several tabs, each of which can contain an .swf. All tabs are defined within the same HTML file and the javascript framework calls a **.rewind()** and **.play()** on the swf when the containing tab becomes active.

This works great on regular flash animation, making sure they start playing from the beginning when the tab is opened. On an swf created with Flex however, the rewind and play wreak havoc on the Flex framework and the application doesn't load.

The best way we've come up with to detect Flex is to count the number of frames the .swf has. With flex that's always 2. But this doesn't sound like the best way.

We've also tried to add a callback method with **ExternalInterface** on the Flex application **preinitialize** event. Unfortunately this event is called quite late in the application startup and the javasctipt code checks the callback before the Flex code has added it.

Is there any other way to detect (from javascript) if the .swf was created using Flex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so, to answer my own question, **DownloadProgressBar** (loaded in the first frame) can be customized (overloaded).

So, this is the custom progress bar, that adds an isFlex() callback method to Javascript:

```
package flexidentifier {
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
    import mx.preloaders.DownloadProgressBar;

    public class FlexIdentifierDownloadProgressBar extends DownloadProgressBar {
        public function FlexIdentifierDownloadProgressBar() {
            super();
            ExternalInterface.addCallback("isFlex", callback);
        }

        protected function callback():String {
        return "true";
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add it to the Application:

```
<s:Application xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" preloader="flexidentifier.FlexIdentifierDownloadProgressBar">
</s:Application>
```

It would have been nice if the people at Adobe put it in the Flex framework to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, no.  Flex *IS* Flash; it's just an added layer on top of Flash to increase productivity in development.

However, there might be a solution for you, but I need to know if you created the swfs yourself and if you can modify them.  If you can, I would use an [ExternalInterface callback](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#addCallback%28%29) to 'play' your swf by calling that function in JS (ie. `document.getDocumentById('swfId').someFunction();`).

The other solution would be to have all your swfs play immediately after load and then only load them in JS when needed (and not doing preloading).  If you need to 'rewind', just reload them again (should be easy enough if you're using [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/), just remove and add back).

Comment: yeah, tried adding a callback through ExternalInterface. Problem is, the soonest I can make that function available is on application preinitialize. I was hoping the Flex framework added it's own callbacks. But I've looked through the SDK sources and haven't found such thing. And I don't think there's a way to insert code in SystemManager, Preloader or DownloadPreogressBar...

Comment: Why not have it play automatically on load?  Also, if you want to have a way to control if a swf auto plays or not, you can always use [FlashVars](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf626ae-7feb.html) which is very easy to implement with SWFObject.

Comment: Thing is, my colleague takes care of the Javascript part and I'm not entirely sure why he's doing it this way. Also, part of the problem is that the actual HTML pages are generated from content created with another tool. But there is actually a way to add a custom DownloadProgressBar. That way the callback (isFlex()) can be added quite early in the Flex startup sequence. I'll post the solution later

Comment: I still think you guys are hacking something together that has a very viable and easy solution to it.  The JS guy doesn't sound too bright...

Comment: Usually, when I use ExternalInterface, I have the SWF call out to JavaScript to give it an "I'm ready, let's do this!" sort of message. After the JS knows the SWF has loaded, only then does it start making calls into the SWF. That way, it doesn't matter how early you add the callback because the JS is expected to wait however long it takes.

Comment: J_A_X strikes again. This man makes a killing off of bashing other people on here.. :) But seriously, he is right, it seems like you are hacking something together that pretty much works out of the box.

Comment: And I'll continue striking as long as there's idiotic people in the world. J_A_X AWAY!

Comment: I'm not going into the discussion of ho it can be done differently in javascript. There's a reason I stay away from it all together! In any case, apart from the hack. It is possible to add a callback very early in Flex's startup sequence, which I posted and is an answer on topic